# Pulling subset of data from Master sheet to individual sheets based on criteria, without using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a master sheet with some sales data, the simplified view is like this:

Date, Product, Quantity, Price, Amount, Customer

Then I have another workbook with individual Customers. I want to be able to pull respective subsets of data from the master sheet and place it to customers sheets based on matching customer's name. The criteria (customer's name) is the A1 cell on each individual Customer's sheet. It would be great if Customer's sheets are dynamically updated when rows are added to the master sheet. The version of Excel is Excel 2016. Is there a way to do it without using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To pull records from one to another Workbook can be accomplished by using this Formula.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX([Master.xlsx]Customer!$A$2:$D$100, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$1, [Master.xlsx]Customer!$A$2:$A$100), ROW([Master.xlsx]Customer!$A$2:$D$100)-MIN(ROW([Master.xlsx]Customer!$A$2:$D$100))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**NB:**

1. Remember it's CSE Formula so finish it with *Clrl+Shift+Enter*.
2. Before you execute this formula, open the MASTER Workbook.
3. In *Cell A1 of Destination Sheet*, write the Name of the Customer, who's records 
   you want to pull from Master File.
4. Write the Formula in the Column A after the Heading Row.
5. In the Cell, you get the Customer Name, drag the formula Write then Down.
6. Drag down the Formula for few Extra Rows, so that when the Same customer will 
   be added in Master File will automatically pull to the Sheet.
7. Repeat these steps to other Sheets, to extract other Customer's records from 
   Master.

*Hope this Help you.*

**Note,** *if you use VBA Code will pull records from Master Workbook even is closed.*